# How to prove simple arithmetic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While reading over someone else's proof of something, I came across the following inequality that was just implied in a step of their proof.

> If $a \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$, and $\frac{1}{a + 1} < b \leq \frac{1}{a}$, then $\frac{a+1}{a} \leq 1 + 2b$.

How can this be shown?

I tried the natural way, i.e. $\frac{a+1}{a} = 1 + \frac{1}{a}$ and then $2b > \frac{2}{a+1} \geq \frac{2}{a+a} = \frac{1}{a}$, but this gives me a strict inequality. For the intent of the proof I am going over, I would expect this to be a non-strict inequality... am I doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I claim that $\frac{2}{1+a}\ge \frac1a$, to see this we just have to cross multiply and we have

$$2a \ge 1+a$$

which is equivalent to

$$a \ge 1$$

which is a true statement.

Hence $$\frac1a \le \frac2{1+a} < 2b$$
adding $1$ to both sides

$$\frac{a+1}{a}\le 1+2b$$

The inequality is strict but it is alright to write "$\le$".

Comment: It was been a while since I have done much calculus. This step is part of proving an inequality for a limit, i.e. proving a limit is equal to $\alpha$ by showing it is $\leq \alpha$ and also $\geq \alpha$. It is fine in this context that the inequality is strict?

Comment: it depends on context, perhaps you can take advantage of the fact that a limit point need not be in the set. For example, even though $\frac1n > 0$. its limit is $0$.

Comment: D'ohh right of course, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ b> \frac {1}{a+1} \ge  \frac{1}{2a} \implies b>\frac {1}{2a} \implies 2b > \frac {1}{a} =  \frac{a+1}{a}  -1 $$

Thus $$\frac{a+1}{a} \leq 1 + 2b$$